# Sphere as identification space of two discs in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Describe the $2-$dimensional sphere as an identification space of two discs in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I am confused on this problem. In the last homeomorphism problem I attempted, the sphere was described as an identification space of the single disk $\{(x,y)| \ x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. What would be the correct way to describe the sphere as an identification space of two discs in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Glue them together at the boundaries.

Comment: @JohnDouma So take two identical disks and identify the sets containing points of the form $x^2+y^2=1$ of both discs to a single equivalence class containing all of these points?

Comment: Yes. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a sphere $S^2$ as the union of its north and south hemispheres. That is, you can think of taking closed $2-$disks $D_1$ and $D_2$ and identifying their boundaries $\partial D_1\cong S^1$ and $\partial D_2\cong S^1$ by a homeomorphism of $S^1$ to itself.